# What App Is Sucking Disk Space?

Tags: windows

Win11, Dell XPS laptop.

Reboot: 21GB free
After some hours, 200MB free, and app start crashing
Reboot: 21GB free

ad nauseum

I use windirstat to see what consumes space, but this is static, when I need dynamic.

Suggestions how to approach?

(I keep opening more and more free space, and never seem to get out of this problem....)

Comment: This is the same question you asked yesterday, that was closed for being a duplicate. You have enough reputation on this site that you should know better how this site works. A "dynamic" disk size detector is just going to be polling the disk more frequently, so refresh WinDirStat or TreeSize, or whatever utility you use. Edit your closed post indicating the selected duplicate does not actually answer your question.

Comment: Get Tree Size and see what is actually happening.  Use the trial version

Comment: I'd guess you may be getting frustrated, you're dealing with some annoying computer issues clearly. But you do not get good answers by posting poorly presented questions here repeatedly. Please take the time to study the previous questions and answers on this topic, and if after doing that you haven't solved the problems you're facing, take the time to modify one of your previous questions carefully to give a full account of your situation

Comment: @John OP should use WizTree instead. Actually free, and very fast. It's been a better alternative for a long time now. But OP also needs to take a step back and study their problem better and present better, clearer (and fewer) questions.

Comment: Both work and provide the proper results.

Comment: 20GB is a substantial amount. Taking screenshots of a "before" and "after" space goes missing might show changes.

Answer (score 0):

Any app that tries to evaluate file system usage over the entire drive would be **extremely** slow. It would be better to look at *current* drive input and output (I/O), which can be done easily with Windows *Task Manager*, or with Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), as shown below.

[image: Disk I/O in Process Explorer]

Clicking on a process, e.g., System, shows details of DLLs, Handles and Threads running under it.